# How to increase the height of the bands?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created a funnel with the below script.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'funnel'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Sales funnel'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: "Sales Chart:<br>{point.name}<br>Cart: {point.value:,.0f}<br>New Users: {point.unique:,.0f}<br>Total Orders Rate: {point.cr}%",
                softConnector: true,
                inside: true,
            },
            neckHeight: "0%",
                neckWidth: "80%",
                width: '15%',
                reversed: true,
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
    name: 'Unique users',
    keys: ["name", "y", "value", "unique", "did", "cr"],
    data: [
      ['Website visits', 1, 659, 541, '1', '1.31'],
      ['Downloads', 1, 392, 288, '38', '0.70'],
      ['Requested price list', 1, 562, 467, '101', '1.13'],
      ['Invoice sent', 1, 338, 282, '97', '0.68' ],
      ['Finalized', 1, 77, 59, '25', '0.14' ]
    ]
  }],
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kiranuk/xhfbyj64/

The band looks crowded. How can I increase the height of the bands?

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c1azjxku/

Comment: Do you really need that first <br>  in `format: "Sales Chart:<br>{point.name}`? Also do you really need to repeat "Sales Chart" for every band?

Comment: @microspino Yes, I need both. It works when we set the chart height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase height of the chart. For example:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'funnel',
    height: 600
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a6sr93fo/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height